# How to correctly parse CSV file with inside quotes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

So as part of a CSV file I'm trying to convert to DataFrame using pd.read_csv() I keep getting this error:

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 2, saw 4
```

The first lines from the file as follows:

1. "yada","yada","yada"
2. "yada","yada","aa bb "yada" cc dd, ee"

The thing is that in the original binary content, the second line's "yada" doesn't have escape char...

What arguments I should include in the read_csv() method in order to have a proper parse of that line by assuming the whole

"aa bb "yada" cc dd, ee"

is one column?

Comment: With the examples given, the problem appears to only appear in the last column. Is this the case for all of the data?

Answer (score 2):

If the quoting problem is only occuring in the final column, then you could massage the data as follows before loading it as a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd      
import csv

data = []

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input:
    for row in csv.reader(f_input, quotechar='\x01'):
        data.append([v.strip('"') for v in row[:2] + [','.join(row[2:])]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)        
print(df)
```

For the data given, this would give you:

```
      0     1                       2
0  yada  yada                    yada
1  yada  yada  aa bb "yada" cc dd, ee
```